# Best describing a stochastic process in terms of others

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, st.statistics, nonlinear-optimization

### Intuitive Question

Suppose I'm given a set of $k$ time-series $\{X_t^1,\dots X_t^k\}$.  Is there a way to determine how much of each series is dependent on the others.

### Formal Question

More precisely if for each $j \in \{1,..,k\}$, $X^j_t$ is a stochastic process with values in $\mathbb{R}$, $\epsilon_t^j$ is a random variable in $\mathbb{R}$ and define the loss function:
$$
\mathfrak{L}_j(a_1,..,a_j):= \int_0^t (1-\sum_{i\neq j, i=1..k} a_i)\sum_{i \neq j i=1..k} (a_i X^i_s - X_s^j)^2 ds
$$

Then how can we determine the best $a_i$ minimizing:
$$
X_t^j = \sum_{i \neq j, i=1..k} a_i X_t^i + a_j\epsilon_t^j,
$$ 
where $\{a^1,...,a^j\}$ are non-negative real numbers such that
$$
\sum_{i=1,..,k} a_i =1
$$
is a convex combination; how can we find the best $a_i$; that is how can we determine the $a_i$ minimizing $\mathfrak{L}(a_1,\dots,a_k)^j$?.

*If it makes things simpler we may assume that the processes are time-series...*

Comment: Hello CSA. The quantity you wish to minimize appears to be stochastic.  So in what sense do you wish to minimize it? In an almost sure, strong, weak or x sense?  Please specify.

Comment: Hi Nawaf, I was aiming for the almost-sure sure sense but if only the weak sense is possible that would still be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Question still unclear. Would you please please check your notations again (range of summation, etc)?.

Comment: Vaguely, one could discretize time and use least squares to find the best $\{ a_i\}$.  However, there are enough ambiguities in the question, to make it difficult to be more specific. E.g., the way it is written it seems like you are asking to minimize a kinematic constraint $X_t^j = \sum_{\substack{1 \le i \le k \\ i \ne j}} a_i X_t^i + a_j \epsilon_t^j$. Its also a bit unclear what role the auxiliary processes $\{ \epsilon_t^j \}$ play.  And, is the goal to minimize the $j$th loss function associated to the $j$th process or the sum of the loss functions from $1$ to $k$.  Please clarify.